# How can I make shading like this?

Tags: shaders, shadows

I'm learning to make models. And I really like this shading style. I can understand the program at a basic level (at a level where I can do toon shading), but I don't know how to make the shadows edge on the model soft and look like they used a low-opacity paintbrush.
[Like this](https://twitter.com/jinhallz/status/1707241023758545362)

[image]

This is the model I have. I have tried making the bushes in [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DEgzuMmJtu8&t=737s). It make the shading close to what I want. But I don't understand how it happened.[image][image][image]

Comment: What have you tried as far?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't tried anything yet. Because I don't know what to do or what tools to use to do it. I'm not sure if it's because of the polygon or shading.

Comment: The look there is greatly influenced by the model itself. What models do you have?

Comment: I have a low polygon tree model.

Comment: It would improve your chances of getting help if you at least shared some screenshots of it. If possible, you could even share the .blend file itself using [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/). It would also be helpful if you could define the goal a bit better - is it animation you are after, or stills?

Comment: Sorry, at first I didn't know how to add it hahaha. Now I've edited and added pictures. I have tried making the bushes in that link. It make the shadow close to what I want. But I don't understand how it happened.

Comment: It's called NPR: Non-Photorealistic Rendering. I think that's the only common denominator between the first and 2nd image in the post.

Comment: The shadows in the first picture look softer than I did. I'd like to know how to make the shadows look like that. Maybe I need to do something to the model?

Comment: I forgot to answer this, I'm after a stills.